# More general permutation of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

For some arbitrary $N$, I would like to construct all permutations of lists of length $n \leq N$ such that the sum of each permutation list adds to a value less than or equal to $N$.

Specifically, for $N = 3$ and $n = 3$, I want to generate these lists:

```
{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{2,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,2},{1,1,1},{3,0,0},{0,3,0},{0,0,3},{2,1,0},{2,0,1},{1,2,0},{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{0,1,2}}
```

As you can see this is more general than using `Permutations[Range[3]]`.

Comment: Your list does not contain e.g. `{1,1,1}`. Is that correct?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, well spotted, I'll edit the question thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Flatten[Map[Permutations, PadRight[#, 3] & /@ IntegerPartitions[#, 3] & /@ Range[3], {-2}], 2]
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing! You win :D

Comment: This is neat, but does it only work $N=n$? How can it be generalised?

Comment: Just susbtitute one of the `3` for `N`, and the other one for `n`, (BTW, next time it is easier if you use two different values for `N,n` instead of `N=n=3`).

Answer (score 5):

Several alternative approaches using (1) [`FrobeniusSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html), (2) [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), (3) [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html), and (4) [`IntegerPartitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3 , f4, f5]
f1[n_, m_] := Join @@ (FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, m], #] & /@ Range[0, n])
f2[n_, m_] := If[Total @ # <= n, #, ## &[]] & /@ Tuples[Range[0, n], {m}]
f3[n_, m_] := Flatten[Outer[If[+## <= n, {##}, ## &[]] &, ## & @@ 
    ConstantArray[Range[0, n], m]], 2]
f4[n_, m_] := Join @@ (Permutations /@ PadRight[Join @@ 
    (IntegerPartitions[#, m] & /@ Range[0, n])])
f5[n_, m_] := Join @@ (Permutations /@ (Join @@ (IntegerPartitions[#, {m}, 
      Range[0, n]] & /@ Range[0, n])))

Sort@f1[3, 3] == Sort@f2[3, 3] == Sort@f3[3, 3] == Sort@f4[3, 3] == Sort@f5[3, 3]
```

> True

```
f1[3, 3]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0,
>      2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 
>     2, 1}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1,
>      0}, {3, 0, 0}}

```
f1[4, 2]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 
>     1}, {3, 0}, {0, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty straightforward way: build all the possible vectors, check if the sum of their elements is <=3. The Flatten and Select remove the ones that don't match.

```
Select[Flatten[Table[If[i + j + k <= 3, {i, j, k}], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, 
               {k, 0, 3}], 2], # =!= Null &]
```

Comment: How can this be generalised for arbitrary $N$ and $n$?